# How to fire a GET request over a pseudo REST service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, http

I need to communicate with legacy php application. The API is just a php scripts than accepts get requests and return a response as XML.

I'd like to write the communication in C#.

**What would be the best approach to fire a GET request (with many parameters) and then parse result?**

Ideally I would like to find something that easy as the python code below:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({
    'action': 'save',
    'note': note,
    'user': user,
    'passwd': passwd,
 })

content = urllib.urlopen('%s?%s' % (theService,params)).read()
data = ElementTree.fromstring(content)
...
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm thinking about using XElement.Load but I don't see a way to easily build the GET query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good utility classes in the [WCF REST Starter Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WCF%20REST), for implementing .NET REST clients that invoke services implemented in any platform.

[Here's a video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Consuming-REST-services-with-HttpClient/) that describes how to use the client-side pieces.

Sample code fragment:

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient("http://twitter.com/statuses");
c.TransportSettings.Credentials = 
    new NetworkCredentials(username, password);
// make a GET request on the resource.
HttpResponseMessage resp = c.Get("public_timeline.xml");
// There are also Methods on HttpClient for put, delete, head, etc
resp.EnsureResponseIsSuccessful(); // throw if not success
// read resp.Content as XElement
resp.Content.ReadAsXElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`System.Net.Webclient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is functionally similar to `python`'s `urllib`.

The `C#` example (slightly edited form the ref above) shows how to "fire a GET request":

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class Test
{
    public static String GetRequest (string theService, string[] params)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the 
        // requested URI contains a query.

        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        string req = theService + "?";
        foreach(string p in params)
            req += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p) + "&";
        Stream data = client.OpenRead ( req.Substring(0, req.Length-1)
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        return = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
}
```

To parse the result, use System.XML classes, or better - [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) classes. A straightforward possibility is the [`XDocument.Load(TextReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) method - you can use the `WebClient` stream returned by `OpenRead()` directly.

Comment: Don't you know any better url builder for .net? The url you are building is invalid. Despite of that you use "?" instead of "&" you haven't escaped params. So that you can easily end up with truncated parameters.

Comment: Sorry, example changed to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String, Encoding)

Comment: There's a url builder, I think, included as part of the WCF REST Starter Kit.